# How to find out console equivalents of Ubuntu System Settings GUI?

Tags: command-line, gui, system-settings

How do I in general find out, what the very nice "System Settings GUI" in Ubuntu (say 12.04) does and how to replicate the changes in command line?

Many people ask questions like "how to change the keyboard rate using command line", and often the answers do not help and are hard to find.

What is the easiest way to find out, what the GUI is actually changing (for various types of settings. I.e. keyboard layout, rate, mouse, network, ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this will answer your question because I don't use GNOME, but you can try running

```
dconf watch /
```

and see if it lists anything while you change the settings.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *general* way to do this.

Most Gnome programs do *not* use command line programs as slaves to set up things.

Sometimes a useful command line program is `apropos` which searches the headlines of man pages for keywords. Settings concerning the handling of your graphics and input system are often X11 utility programs.

If you want to control behavior of your Gnome desktop you are often stuck with graphical Gnome programs.