# Capture commands executed when a setting is changed

Tags: command-line, gnome, sound

Let's say I go to Settings → *Sound* → *Output Device* → *HDMI*.

Is there a way to debug/log/capture the shell command which gets executed to save this setting?

Comment: I don't think that the settings manager (to stay with your example) executes a shell command at all. There might be an equivalent shell command which does the same.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [How to find out console equivalents of Ubuntu System Settings GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175382/how-to-find-out-console-equivalents-of-ubuntu-system-settings-gui) . See also [GUI to CLI command translator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986896/gui-to-cli-command-translator)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pacmd list-sources` to view output devices